# Show dialog in the client device only - Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to show a dialog in the connected device only, not on both the server and client device. Is that possible? Thanks

Comment: which dialog? How you show it on both devices?

Comment: only Bluetooth Low Energy(BLE) devices support this usecase. i don't think it's possible